# Разложить значение исходного столбца по пробелам в новые столбцы с подсчётом числа совпадений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть Excel файл с данными, в котором есть один столбец, где записано имя, фамилия и отчество. Они разделены пробелами. Как выглядит интересующий нас столбец:

```
    HeadName
    Климачев Андрей Анатольевич
    Харитонова Надежда Ивановна
...
```

Привожу часть таблицы в фото, так как не могу её сюда вставить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести отдельно имя, отдельно фамилию и отчество, и
посчитать отдельно каких имен и каких фамилий больше. То есть, код должен обращаться к столбцу  `HeadName` в таблице `data4` (в ней уже удалены пропуски данных) и разделять первое, второе и третье слово, узнавая их по пробелам.

Попробовала такой код:

```
our_name = data4.groupby('HeadName')
our_name.HeadName = [i.split(' ')[0] for i in list(our_name.HeadName)]
our_name.HeadName.value_counts().head(5)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Так примерно должен выглядеть отформатированный вариант для подсчета имен:

```
Panula        5
Goodwin       4
Gustafsson    4
Rice          4
Sage          4
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: убедительная просьба впредь приводить хотя бы часть исходных данных, если вы вообще хотите получить ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные для примера я позаимствовал из ответа @strawdog (только переставил фамилии вперед, чтобы было как в вопросе):

```
In [1]: %paste
df= pd.DataFrame(
   {"HeadName":["Иванов Василий Иванович",
                "Петров Василий Петрович",
                "Петров ПетровПетр Петрович",
                "Иванов ИвановИван Иванович",
                "Иванов ИвановИван Петрович",
                "Сидоров СидороИван Иванович"]})
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                      HeadName
0      Иванов Василий Иванович
1      Петров Василий Петрович
2   Петров ПетровПетр Петрович
3   Иванов ИвановИван Иванович
4   Иванов ИвановИван Петрович
5  Сидоров СидороИван Иванович
```

чтобы разложить ФИО по столбцам можно воспользоваться методом [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [3]: df[['LastName','FirstName', 'Patronym']] = \
            df['HeadName'].str.extract(r'(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)')

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
                      HeadName LastName   FirstName  Patronym
0      Иванов Василий Иванович   Иванов     Василий  Иванович
1      Петров Василий Петрович   Петров     Василий  Петрович
2   Петров ПетровПетр Петрович   Петров  ПетровПетр  Петрович
3   Иванов ИвановИван Иванович   Иванов  ИвановИван  Иванович
4   Иванов ИвановИван Петрович   Иванов  ИвановИван  Петрович
5  Сидоров СидороИван Иванович  Сидоров  СидороИван  Иванович

In [5]: df['LastName'].value_counts()
Out[5]:
Иванов     3
Петров     2
Сидоров    1
Name: LastName, dtype: int64
```

Comment: да, extract - это тема. удобно сразу раскидывать по столбцам. почему-то мне такой вариант сразу на ум не пришел

Comment: @strawdog, удобная вещь, постоянно пользуюсь... :)

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, вы несколько всё усложняете.

```
import pandas as pd
d ={"HeadName":["Василий Иванович Иванов",
                "Василий Петрович Петров",
                "Петр Петрович Петров",
                "Иван Иванович Иванов",
                "Иван Петрович Иванов",
                "Иван Иванович Сидоров"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Дейтафрейм для примера:

```
                 HeadName
0  Василий Иванович Иванов
1  Василий Петрович Петров
2     Петр Петрович Петров
3     Иван Иванович Иванов
4     Иван Петрович Иванов
5    Иван Иванович Сидоров
```

Ну и, собственно, ваш value_counts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df["HeadName"].str.split(' ', expand=True).values,
             columns=['FirstName', 'Patronym', 'LastName'])
#  FirstName  Patronym LastName
#0   Василий  Иванович   Иванов
#1   Василий  Петрович   Петров
#2      Петр  Петрович   Петров
#3      Иван  Иванович   Иванов
#4      Иван  Петрович   Иванов
#5      Иван  Иванович  Сидоров


df["LastName"].value_counts()
```

На выходе:

```
Иванов     3
Петров     2
Сидоров    1
Name: LastName, dtype: int64
```

Comment: ваш код работает @strawdog но как применить его к значениям в строке HeadName а не "забитым" вручную именам?

Comment: @user329688 вручную "забитые" имена формируют такой же дейтафрейм как и тот, что вы описали в задании. по крайней мере, пока вы не предоставили других исходных данных, я не вижу никаких отличий.

Answer (score 1):

Сделаем `split` в столбце

```py
expanded = data4['HeadName'].str.split(n=2, expand=True)
data4['Surname'] = expanded[0]
data4['Name'] = expanded[1]
data4['Patronym'] = expanded[2]
```

Сгруппируем и посчитаем кол-во

```py
surname_count = data4.groupby('Surname').count()
name_count = data4.groupby('Name').count()
```

`*_count` - это `pd.DataFrame`-ы, где в каждой строке находится уникальное(ая) имя(фамилия) и их количество

Comment: вышла не ошибка, а предупреждение @MrMorgan.  SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: @user329688 укажите строку. у меня такого предупреждения нет.

Comment: направлено не к определенной строке -продолжение предупреждения
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Comment: @user329688 строку кода, я имел ввиду.